# How can I prove that if $\{X_n\}_{n∈ℕ}$ and $\{X_n+Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ both converge, then $\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I proof that if $\{X_n\}_{n∈ℕ}$ converges and $\{X_n+Y_n\}_{n∈ℕ}$ converges, then $\{Y_n\}_{n∈ℕ}$ converges?

My initial thought was using the definition of $X_n\to L$ when $n$ tends to infinity and the same with $X_n+Y_n,$ but I get stuck finding the epsilon, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: **Hint:** $Y_n=(X_n+Y_n)-X_n$.